# How to resolve angular memory leak

Tags: javascript, angular, optimization, memory-leaks

In order to optimize Garbage Collector manually, how can we forcefully push variables to the garbage collector? Like if we have a root/global level variable in one angular component, and then when we are switching from that page to another - we won't need the global variables in that page? How can we move to garbage collector?

If we do variable = null or variable = undefined on ngOnDestroy() like we unsubscribe from observables, would that help?

Comment: No, nullifying does in general not help, unless the property/variable will continue existing for some reason and you just don't want it to refer to some other object any more.

Comment: Do you really mean a *global* variable that is shared by all instances of the component?

Answer (score 2):

Strategies to prevent leaks

- Nullify all references to models in a component on the component
  $destroy phase
- Try to remove all circular dependencies by using yet another layer of
  indirection
- Create a this.state object to manage the instance state in a place
  for easier nullification
- Dispose subscriptions
- Examine third party software and decide to use it or not also based
  on memory problems or contribute with PRs

Comment: The first three points look a lot like cargo cult practices. No, you should not generally "nullify all references", that's really pointless and only contributes to spread the cult. You only need to do it when you have factual evidence that a reference keeps objects alive longer than they are actually needed.